# C# how to install Windows.Media.Transcoding

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, .net-assembly

In my current project I need to use the Windows Media Transcoding API. However, I can't manage to install it.

Here you can see I'm using the correct namespace.

```
using System.Windows.Media.Transcoding;
```

I looked around on NuGet, but couldn't find it there. I read the Microsoft page about it, but that only told me the namespace. I also couldn't find it's Assembly. Could someone please help me install it.

Comment: Sorry for being so nooby, I can already feel the down votes :(

Comment: This is not a separate Nuget package, its part of Windows Runtime APi..are you targeting UWP?

Comment: No, its just a Visual C# application in .NET

Comment: using what framework and targeting what? WinForms, WPF, Console?

Comment: Windows Forms application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow these instructions:

Modify the target platform by opening your .csproj file with an external editor and add the line

```
<TargetPlatformVersion>8.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
```

as for this example

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{6D41F51D-5A85-4826-9868-14FB3591F280}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>WindowsFormsApplication1</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>UseWindowsMediaTranscodingAPI</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <TargetPlatformVersion>8.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Reload the solution and add a reference to Windows Core Media DLL

[image: add reference to Windows Core Media]

This should already compile.

Additionally to be able handle events and async methods mapping you should add the reference to the system dll:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime

Remember that the application will work only on Windows 10.

Source: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdndevs/2013/10/02/using-windows-8-winrt-apis-in-net-desktop-applications/